# Multiple Lines (HTML and JSP) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I'm trying to declare a String in Javascript which spans multiple lines. The lines consist of HTML and some JSP.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
function doSth() {

var longString = ["<table>"
        ,"<tr>"
        ,"<td>"
        ,"<select name=dropdownList size=1>",
        ,"<option value="0" selected>- Select Cake -</option>",
        <%  
            for (int i=0; i<cakes.size(); i++) { 
                String cake = cakes.get(i).toString();
                String selectedCake = "";
        %>
        "<option value='<%=cakes.get(i)%>' <%=selectedCake%> >     <%=cakes.get(i+1)%></option>",
        <%
            }
        %>
        ,"</select>"
        ,"</td>"
        ,"</tr>"
        ].join("");

}
```

Eclipse says there is a syntax error, but I am not able to pinpoint the error.

Edit: Sorry I changed the sample code to better reflect my situation.

Comment: What is the file type of this source file?  It isn't clear from your question.  Is it .js, or .jsp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that this string has unescaped double-quotes in it?:

```
"<input type="button" name="helloButton" value="Click Me">"
```

Try changing it to:

```
"<input type=\"button\" name=\"helloButton\" value=\"Click Me\">"
```

or even better:

```
"<input type='button' name='helloButton' value='Click Me'>"
```

Comment: Note (for OP): Stack Overflow's syntax colour-highlighting helps in finding this error (if that line were a valid string it would all be one colour).

Comment: You're welcome. Ironically that tip didn't work on your updated code (presumably because numeric literals get the same colour as string literals), but you've got the same problem on the line `"<option value="0" selected>- Select Bank -</option>"` (need to use single-quotes for the `value` attribute).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Ned. I've updated my code to a new sample, but the same problem persists.

Comment: The code in the question still shows the error I pointed out here.  Perhaps you could tell us what line number Eclipse is complaining about?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem! It is indeed with the single,double quotes!